# moving average function matlab (without the use of a for loop)

Tags: matlab, variables, persistent, moving-average

I am trying to complete a matlab assignment project with the following question:

Write a function called moving_average that takes a scalar called x as an input argument and returns a scalar. The function uses a “buffer” to hold previous inputs, and the buffer can hold a maximum of 25 inputs. Specifically, the function must save the most recent 25 inputs in a vector (the buffer). Each time the function is called, it copies the input argument into an element of the buffer. If there are already 25 inputs stored in the buffer, it discards the oldest element and saves the current one in the buffer. After it has stored the input in the buffer, it returns the mean of all the elements in the buffer.

The solution I provide is the following:

```
function ma = moving_average (x)
    persistent buffer;
    if isempty(buffer)
        buffer = x; ma = mean(x);
    else buffer = [buffer x];
        if numel(buffer) <= 25
            ma = mean(buffer); 
        else
            ma = mean([buffer(end-24) buffer(end)]);
        end
    end
```

According to the auto grader my function performs correctly when values 1-50 are passing consecutively, but fails when values of a noisy sine wave are passing consecutively (which I have been informed that might be due to some sort of a round off error).

I would be grateful if any of you could provide me some hints regarding the possible error steps in my code (appended above).

Thank you in advance

Comment: By the way, usually when you use a moving average, you keep the sum of all elements, and only add the new added element and subtract the old discarded element at each step, and then divide by the number of elements to get the average. This way you are only performing two addition operations per step, so the speed is O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only averageing the last and the 25th from last.

use:

```
ma = mean(buffer(end-24:end));
```

Comment on your code:
It will perform well, if your function is not called often. But, if the function is called a lot of times, your `buffer`will get bigger and bigger. This is a possible memory leak. You should consider only keeping 25 values in your buffer:

```
if length(buffer) > 25
   buffer = buffer(end-24:end);
end
```

Comment: Dear Steffen,

Thank you very much for you prompt and truly illuminating reply! You know what they say..sometimes after persistent work on something you miss the simplest points..please excuse my frivolous approach on the mean function but I am only working with matlab for less than a month now.   

Regarding the "memory leak issue" I will definitely have that in mind and in the future I will follow your advice.  

Once more thank you for your time.

Enjoy the rest of your day